# Python subprocess.Popen not working when stdout=tempfile is used

Tags: python, subprocess

I have Python script that runs some tests using *subprocess.Popen()* without blocking.

```
import datetime, os,subprocess, tempfile, time

tempfile.tempdir = None
tempFile = tempfile.TemporaryFile( bufsize=0 )
#args = ['ls'] # or whatever, to reproduce
process = subprocess.Popen( args, shell=False, bufsize=0, stdout=tempFile,
                            stderr=tempFile, preexec_fn=os.setsid, env=os.environ )


while process.poll() is None:
    time.sleep( 5 )
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
```

*process* is not returning any error.

If I remove **stdout=tempFile** then the test runs without any problem.

I'm using Python 2.7.3

Comment: Seems to work for me, with that code. What are you using to check whether the tests run?

Comment: Seems to work for me too. What exactly does "not working" mean? Error (show stacktrace)? Hang? What *args* did you  use, btw?

Comment: unrelated: bufsize doesn't matter unless you use `subprocess.PIPE`. You can close `tempFile` immediately after the Popen call (the child has its own copy). You could use `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT`. `env=os.environ` is unnecessary (it is a default). You could add `close_fds=sys.platform != 'win32'`. Why do you use `os.setsid`? (do you want to kill child's process tree?). You could use `subprocess.call()` instead of `Popen + while  p.poll() is None` loop.

Comment: The code in the question should work as is. Create a [minimal *complete* code example that demonstrates the issue](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What I meant by it's not working is, I don't see expected output in the tempFile and _subprocess.Popen_ returns without any error/exception. When remove _stdout=tempFile_ I see output on terminal. The code should work but it is not. Unable to reproduce with other binaries. Also problem is present when I used normal file instead of _tempfile_

Comment: [edit] your question and include this info there. The question should be complete without comments.

Comment: what happens if you run your executable from the command line but redirect output to a pipe: `your-exec | cat`? Why do you need `tempFile` here?

Comment: Upon more debugging it is found our that its not the problem of python script but redirection of stdout itself. How can I close this question?